# Reading Data from the web in chunks using HttpClient C#

Tags: web, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, chunks, data-stream

I am trying to call the web and receive the data that it send back in chunks. So in other words I am trying to receive from the web and print it, while more data is coming in. But I can not find anything that has code examples in it. What I can find says to pass HttpCompletionOption into the httpClient.SendAsync function but I have no clue what to do after that.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url))
    {
        string content = "{ \"exampleJson\": \"This is an example\" }";

        request.Content = new StringContent(content);

        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // But what do I do to get the json data as it is coming in from the web?

        return;

    }
}
```

But now what do I do to get the JSON data from the web as it is coming in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed to do. I replaced this code

```
// But what do I do to get the json data as it is coming in from the web?
```

with this new code

```
// Check if the response is successful
if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseString = "";
    // Read the response data in chunks
    using (Stream responseStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                responseString += new string(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answers should *explain* what they changed and *how* it solves the problem. They shouldn't be dumps of code which people are expected to play a game of spot-the-dfference with.

Comment: Suggest you edit you answer with a line or two to show what changed, and ideally why.   it will help people who may trip over an issue in a similar way to that in the Question.