How to reduce the response time in C# while calling an API from projeqtor?
I need to get all the tickets from Projeqtor using the '../projeqtor/api/ticket/all' endpoint. However, this endpoint returns a large amount of data, resulting in long response times. Since the Projeqtor API does not support pagination, how can I request the API in a way that avoids excessive data retrieval and reduces response time, similar to how it's done within Projeqtor itself? The specific line causing the delay is:
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(apiUrlProjeqtor);
    public async Task<string> GetAllTicketsFromProjqtorAsync()
    {
        string apiUrl = _apiProjqtorUrl + "Ticket/all";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return $"Error: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }


You could try streaming the data? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457375/4079967
